# Can't uncheck programatically after manual check on a checkbox: Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

Once checked from UI(clicking on `checkbox`), I am not able to uncheck the checkbox programatically.

[In the sample app](https://angular-k4ntwb.stackblitz.io), click on the checkbox to check it. Now click on the 'Un Check' button. The property in the background changes to false, but the checkbox wont un-check.

**Note:**

If not manually checked, both checking and unchecking works programatically.

[Link to the code editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4ntwb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `input [checked]` is an one way binding.

You need 2 way binding or to be more precise, you now can get but can't set the value. And with that, you may need a setter with your logic.

- If you wont use `ngModel` like you do in your code, use the `(change)` event to set the new value and a setter:

  ```
  get IsChecked(): boolean {
    return this._isChecked;
  }
  set IsChecked(val) {
    this._isChecked = val;
  }
  ```

  and html: `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="IsChecked" (change)="IsChecked = !IsChecked"/>`
- Another way is to use `ngModel`.

`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="IsChecked"/>`
which if developed is:

`<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="IsChecked" (ngModelChange)="IsChecked = !$event"/>`
 which do the same as `[checked]` and `(change)`

Comment: Why its not working without a setter. The idea was to bind one-way only. I didn't wish to update my model when user clicks checkbox. but programatically/timely from background. Is the binding gets broken once I manually click the checkbox. because the label still shows expected value?

Comment: because you need to update the private value _isChecked, you can't access it via the html directly. take a look on "accessors" https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: if you dont want to use an accessor use a method:  `(change)="updateIsChecked($event)"` and TS: `updateIsChecked() { this._isChecked = !this._isChecked; }`

Answer (score 0):

Change the input in `app.component.html` to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="IsChecked" (change)="onCheckedChanged()" />
```

and add the following to your `app.component.ts`:

```
  onCheckedChanged() {
   this._isChecked = !this._isChecked;
  }
```

### Why:

while you correctly bound the checked attribute to the `IsChecked` getter, this only reflects changes to `IsChecked`, so the buttons are working.

`IsChecked` is not changing when you click on the tick of the input field, therefore you have to listen to the change event and programmatically update the `IsChecked` (actually the `this._isChecked`) property.

As a side note, as far as I know the convention for class fields in Typescript and angular is to start the literal in lower case.